# Issue creating a select tag with a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

I need to create a list of select tags that go into a join table. I have created this loop

```
- @game_details.fighting_game_main_characters.each do |main_character|
  = simple_fields_for :combo_book_combo_works do |works|
    = main_character.name
    = works.input :fighting_game_main_character_id, as: :hidden, 
      input_html: {value: main_character.id}
    = works.select :test, ["Works", "Doesn't Work", "Untested"], {}, 
      selected: "Untested", class: "form-control"
```

add it shows up as expected. When I hit submit It dose not write to the join table. I looked at the log and saw that only the last select tag was in the submitted params

```
Parameters: 
{
    "utf8"=>"✓", 
    "combo_book_combo"=>{
    "combo_book_combo_characters_attributes"=>
        {"0"=>{"fighting_game_main_character_id"=>"1"}
    }, 
    "combo_type"=>"Combo", 
    "character_positions"=>"Ground to Ground", 
    "screen_position"=>"Midscreen", 
    "combo"=>"ô"
    },
    "keyboard-select"=>"", 
    "combo_book_combo_works"=>{
        "fighting_game_main_character_id"=>"13", 
        "test"=>"Works"}, 
    "commit"=>"Add combo"
}
```

I looks a the page source and saw that all of the select had the same ID so I added

```
id: "combo_book_combo_works_#{main_character.id}"
```

But that didn't solve the problem as it still didn't write to the join table so I looked at the models

```
class ComboBookCombo < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :combo_book_combo_characters
  has_many :fighting_game_main_characters, through: :combo_book_combo_characters

  has_many :combo_book_combo_assists
  has_many :fighting_game_assist_characters, through: :combo_book_combo_assists

  has_many :combo_book_combo_character_extras
  has_many :fighting_game_main_character_extras, through: :combo_book_combo_character_extras

  has_many :combo_book_combo_works
  has_many :fighting_game_main_characters, through: :combo_book_combo_works

  has_many :combo_book_combo_extras
  has_many :fighting_game_extras, through: :combo_book_combo_extras

  validates :combo, :combo_type, :character_positions, :screen_position, presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :combo_book_combo_characters, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['fighting_game_main_character_id'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :combo_book_combo_assists, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['fighting_game_assist_character_id'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :combo_book_combo_character_extras, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['fighting_game_charater_extra_id'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :combo_book_combo_extras, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['fighting_game_extra_id'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :combo_book_combo_works, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['fighting_game_main_charater_id'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true

  belongs_to :combo_book_user
end

class ComboBookComboWork < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :combo_book_combo, optional: true
  belongs_to :fighting_game_main_character
end


class FightingGameMainCharacter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :fighting_game

  has_many :fighting_game_main_character_extras

  has_many :combo_book_combo_characters
  has_many :combo_book_combos, through: :combo_book_combo_characters

  has_many :combo_book_combo_works
  has_many :combo_book_combos, through: :combo_book_combo_works

end
```

and then the controller

```
def create
    @combo_book_combo = current_combo_book_user.combo_book_combos.build(combo_book_combo_params)
    if @combo_book_combo.save
      render 'index', notice: "Successfully created combo"
    else
      render 'index', notice: "Error creating combo"
    end
 end
```

and the required params

```
def combo_book_combo_params
  params.require(:combo_book_combo).permit(
    :fighting_game_main_character_id,
    :combo, 
    :combo_type, 
    :character_positions, 
    :combo_type, 
    :screen_position, 
    combo_book_combo_assists_attributes: [:id, :fighting_game_assist_character_id, :combo_book_combo_id, :_destroy],
    combo_book_combo_character_extras_attributes: [:id, :combo_book_combo_id, :fighting_game_id, :_destroy],
    combo_book_combo_extras_attributes:[:id, :combo_book_combo_id, :fighting_game_extra_id, :_destroy],
    combo_book_combo_characters_attributes:[:id, :fighting_game_main_character_id, :combo_book_combo_id, :_destroy],
    combo_book_combo_works_attributes:[:id, :combo_book_combo_id, :fighting_game_main_character_id, :test]
  )
end
```

and everything seems to be fine with them but when I submit again i get

```
ComboBookUser Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "combo_book_users".* FROM "combo_book_users" WHERE "combo_book_users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "combo_book_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "combo_book_combos" ("combo", "combo_type", "character_positions", "screen_position", "created_at", "updated_at", "combo_book_user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["combo", "ô"], ["combo_type", "Combo"], ["character_positions", "Ground to Ground"], ["screen_position", "Midscreen"], ["created_at", 2016-11-26 19:48:19 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-11-26 19:48:19 UTC], ["combo_book_user_id", "2"]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "combo_book_combo_characters" ("combo_book_combo_id", "fighting_game_main_character_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["combo_book_combo_id", 52], ["fighting_game_main_character_id", 1], ["created_at", 2016-11-26 19:48:19 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-11-26 19:48:19 UTC]]
   (2.3ms)  COMMIT
  Rendering combo_book_combos/index.html.haml within layouts/application
  Rendered combo_book_combos/index.html.haml within layouts/application (1.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 76ms (Views: 61.7ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
```

The join that need to be written to is not showing up. What do I need to do to make all the select tags generated by the loop write to the join table?

Comment: It looks like your `"combo_book_combo_works"` params are not nested as part of the `" combo_book_combo"` params. You'll need to rework the form code so that the works attributes are passed along as part of the same hash as the combo_book_combo params.

Comment: I added the combo_book_combo params. How do you think I should rework my form?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is expecting all params to be passed in as nested values underneath the `combo_book_combo` value. That's what this method is trying to do:

```
def combo_book_combo_params
    params.require(:combo_book_combo).permit(
    :fighting_game_main_character_id, 
    :combo, :combo_type,
    :character_positions, 
    :combo_type, 
    :screen_position, 
    combo_book_combo_assists_attributes: [
        :id, 
        :fighting_game_assist_character_id, 
        :combo_book_combo_id, 
        :_destroy],
    combo_book_combo_character_extras_attributes: [
        :id, 
        :combo_book_combo_id, 
        :fighting_game_id, 
        :_destroy],
    combo_book_combo_extras_attributes:[
        :id, 
        :combo_book_combo_id, 
        :fighting_game_extra_id, 
        :_destroy],
    # etc
    )
end
```

This is what your parameters currently look like:

```
{ 
    "combo_book_combo"=>{
        "combo_book_combo_characters_attributes"=>{
            "0"=>{"fighting_game_main_character_id"=>"1"}
        }, 
        "combo_type"=>"Combo", 
        "character_positions"=>"Ground to Ground", 
        "screen_position"=>"Midscreen", 
        "combo"=>"ô"
    }, 
    "combo_book_combo_works"=>{
        "fighting_game_main_character_id"=>"13", 
        "test"=>"Works"
    },
}
```

This is what your controller *expects* your parameters to look like:

```
{ 
    "combo_book_combo"=>{
        "combo_book_combo_characters_attributes"=>{
            "0"=>{"fighting_game_main_character_id"=>"1"}
        }, 
        "combo_type"=>"Combo", 
        "character_positions"=>"Ground to Ground", 
        "screen_position"=>"Midscreen", 
        "combo"=>"ô",
        "combo_book_combo_works_attributes"=>{
            "fighting_game_main_character_id"=>"13", 
            "test"=>"Works"
        }, 
    },
}
```

Note that the `combo_book_combo_works` have moved *inside* the `combo_book_combo` params, *and* the key has changed to `combo_book_combo_works_attributes`.

Take a look at your form right now, particularly the bit for `combo_book_combo_characters_attributes` - it looks like that part of the form was correctly built out with nested form attributes. You're probably going to change `simple_fields_for` so that it is a method called on the parent form (something like `f.simple_fields_for`) rather than a standalone view helper method call.

Comment: I added `= f.simple_fields_for :combo_book_combo_works do |works|` but now all the names and select tags are gone, and when I view source there not there also.

Comment: does the 'combo book combo' object have any "works" initialized or saved? Simple_fields_for will loop through any existing objects, if there are any, but it won't initialize a blank one - you may need to build a 'work' object so the form fields are displayed.

Comment: it swapped  `- @game_details.fighting_game_main_characters.each do |main_character|` and `= f.simple_fields_for :combo_book_combo_works do |works|` and all the names and select tags show up, but it still not writing to the join table and only the last select tag is showing up in the params passed.
`

Comment: Look at the 'strong parameters' example on this page: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models (actually that whole page is pretty helpful).